# Is wheel dish important?

Tags: wheels

It makes sense that ideally a wheel should be dished well (close to centered), but what are the consequences of a wheel being out of dish but otherwise true?

Comment: Your brakes may not work and the wheel will be weaker than a properly dished wheel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, these are the only possible consequences:

- Your tire may rub on your frame.
- You might have trouble getting your brakes to work (assuming you have rim brakes).
- Your bike might run a bit sideways if your rear wheel is not centered on the frame. This can make riding no-hands difficult, because the bike wants to drift to the side.

Comment: The issue with rim brakes is probably the most significant. If the wheel is not centered in the frame then the shoes have to be set wider than they would otherwise need to be. One of the shoes will be close to the rim, but the other will be farther away. I'd expect that this would mean that you might not get as much braking power (for example, with cantilevers with the straddle cable clamped you'll be pulling against the rim as soon as the first shoe hits, to get the other shoe to contact the rim the brakes will need to push the rim towards it).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this issue.  At least on my bike, the brakes can be centered to the wheel so they're always pressing evenly.

Comment: Great! some brake types won't work very well when the wheel is off center on the frame.